# React Navigation: Setting header title with multiple instances of same screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation (https://reactnavigation.org) to handle navigation in my React Native app. The app structure consists of a StackNavigator with a bunch of nested menus. All the menus use the same MenuScreen component.

When I navigate through 2+ menus, then press the back button, the navigation bar title doesn't change back. It gets stuck on the title set by the "furthest" menu reached.

This makes sense, since I set the static `navigationOptions` property in the constructor of each successive MenuScreen, but never change it back. What is the best practice for fixing this?

Comment: Post navigationOptions code here for better understanding.

Comment: Have you managed to fixed it? It looks to be similiar to my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510356/implement-a-file-explorer-using-stacknavigator-issue-when-going-back-to-the-roo). The `goBack` function seems to cause a lot of issue...